# Can I use vlookup or match/index to look up data to the left for more than look up value?

Tags: excel

[image]

This is the data I have.
I want to see if I can look up all the Korean stocks. So the input value should be "SOUTH KOREA" and the result table/array should look like this:
[image]

Apparately, I can't use VLOOKUP because 1) the lookup value (country name) is on the right column and 2) it will return the first value (STOCK A) only. I need to return all the values (STOCK A, STOCK B, STOCK E, AND STOCK F). I would really appreciate help!

Comment: How about using filters?

Comment: @oh I have to automate a process.

Comment: Then use pivot table and slicers.

Comment: @zipa I can't use pivot table for this work. I have to use either existing excel functions or vba

Comment: these information should have been in the question, and it's sounding more and more like homework to me. Short answer to your original question: no, you cannot use vlookup or match/index because of the limitation that they return a single value.

Comment: You can use `INDEX` function in conjunction with `SMALL`. It will be array formula.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij could you please explain to me how to use them please?

Comment: You could use a worksheet filled with formulae using index/match/small, but I wouldn't count that as a viable solution, and it will potentially be slow if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I mean it seems far more logical to utilize the inbuilt filter function, but if you absolutely insist on using formulas / code then:*

Just use this simple procedure

```
Private Sub sort_wares(From As String, toColumn As Integer)

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim index As Integer
    index = 2

    For Each Rng In tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
        If Trim(LCase(Rng)) = Trim(LCase(From)) Then

            ws.Cells(index, toColumn + 1) = Rng
            ws.Cells(index, toColumn) = Rng.Offset(0, -1)

            index = index + 1
        End If

    Next Rng
End Sub
```

You can easily invoke the procedure, so for example if we from the following data wanted to look up all the wares from Zimbabwe and print them to the 5th Column (E) we would do the following

`Call sort_wares("Zimbabwe", 5)`

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. Actually, the problem is that the data (Wares and Country) are in a different worksheet. So I have to go to the different worksheet.

Comment: @JunJang Hello, just reference the different worksheets  then! Check in my code how I stored the worksheet "Sheet1" in my `ws` variable. Create a second one akin to the one I created and then just apply it to where you want the data to be pasted. If you are still not sure as to how, please edit your question with the exact sheet names and data and I'll update my answer accordingly!

Comment: thank you very much.. So the data (Stock and Country) are stored in "Sheet 1". The user wants to provide the input value (country name) in "Sheet 2" and return the list of stocks in "Sheet 2".

Comment: Also, may I ask you what the "Table1" is?

Comment: Where exactly is the value input? Inside an inputbox or just a cell? 
And Table1 is the data stored in my picture (with black header and border). It's usually better to use Tables than Ranges, because Table indices it's own Rows, rather than Range being a static reference that falls apart if you change (what I'm saying is - if you started your range in the code from row 2, and somebody added extra row, your entire code would fall apart. Hence it's preferable to use the table)

Comment: Value input is just a cell. (Let's say cell C1). How did you create Table 1 variable and store the data in the table?

Comment: Actually, I just figured out! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Alright, glad that it helped :) Maybe one small trick, if you haven't figured it out by now. You can (if the value will always be input  in cell C1) change the code the followign way: `Private Sub  sort_wares(toColumn as Integer)` and then one more line `If Trim(LCase(Rng)) = Trim(LCase(ws2.Range("C1").Value2))` This will always use the value inside C1 as lookup value instead. So now you just can just call the procedure with `Call sort_wares(toColumn)`  *Note, presuming in ws2 variable there is your second worksheet stored (the one with C1)*

Comment: Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function. Note that it is array formula which needs to be committed by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> simultaneously. Excel will wrap formula with `{}` if done correctly!

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$1000="SOUTH KOREA",ROW($B$1:$B$1000)),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

You can replace `"SOUTH KOREA"` by a cell reference.

Adjust the ranges to suit and copy down as much as you need.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. I just tried but it only returns the first value (STOCK A).. I highlighted multiple cells, pressed F2, typed the formula in, and then pressed ctrl+shift+enter, but all the cells say STOCK A

Comment: @JunJang No such issues at my end. See file kept on DropBox https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nrhjbsx8irz2br/SO_50741053.xlsx?dl=0